# Can the <label> element be used with an <output> element?

Tags: html, label

Can the `<label>` HTML element refer to (either by having it as a child or via the `for` attribute) an `<output>` element instead of an `<input>` (which is the far more common use)? Is this allowed by the HTML5 spec?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. [According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/output), the `<output>` is a "labelable element," which are "Elements that can be associated with `<label>` elements" [(source)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Form_labelable).

Also, the [W3C Markup Validator](http://validator.w3.org/) successfully checked the following document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Can a label be used for an output?</title>

<label for="out">This is the label.</label>
<output id="out">This is the output.</output>
```